# Installing MySQLdb for python2.7 returns error

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pip, mysql-python, python-2.x

I'm currently trying to install MySQLdb for python2.7 on a RHEL8 server.

When trying to install through pip the module `mysql (same output for mysql-python)` i receive the following output (the output has changed several times based on my tries, more exactly I had to update gcc, then to install the mysql pkg through yum/dnf, update setuptools through pip as well as through yum/dnf etc.):

```
Collecting mysql
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/5f/b574ac9f70811df0540e403309f349a8b9fa1a25d3653824c32e52cc1f28/mysql-0.0.2.tar.gz
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7gpRJR/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9H4yC_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/include/mysql/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
     #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
      ^~~~~~~
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
      if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                             ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7gpRJR/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9H4yC_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7gpRJR/MySQL-python/
```

Currently I have installed through yum the following rpms:

```
mysql-errmsg-8.0.21-1.module+el8.2.0+7855+47abd494.x86_64
mysql-devel-8.0.21-1.module+el8.2.0+7855+47abd494.x86_64
mysql-common-8.0.21-1.module+el8.2.0+7855+47abd494.x86_64
mysql-8.0.21-1.module+el8.2.0+7855+47abd494.x86_64
mysql-server-8.0.21-1.module+el8.2.0+7855+47abd494.x86_64
mysql-libs-8.0.21-1.module+el8.2.0+7855+47abd494.x86_64
python2-setuptools-39.0.1-12.module+el8.3.0+7075+8484f0d0.noarch
platform-python-pip-9.0.3-18.el8.noarch
python2-libs-2.7.17-2.module+el8.3.0+7681+f1f02ded.x86_64
python2-pip-wheel-9.0.3-18.module+el8.3.0+7707+eb4bba01.noarch
python2-devel-2.7.17-2.module+el8.3.0+7681+f1f02ded.x86_64
```

Also I have the following modules installed through pip:

```
setuptools (44.1.1)
mysql-connector-python (8.0.23)
pip (9.0.3)
```

Any chance you could suggest on what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you thought about switching to 3.9.2?

Comment: It's required I have to work on 2.7 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb is too old for your new MySQL. See https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/:

> MySQL-3.23 **through 5.5** … are currently supported

My advice is to try one of the following:

https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

```
pip install "mysqlclient<2.0"
```

https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/

```
pip install "PyMySQL<1.0"
```